# Installing GitPython on Windows 7

Tags: python, gitpython

I do not seem to be able to install GitPython in my windows 7 environment. I have tried both GitPython-0.1.7 and GitPython-0.3.2.RC1 on both python-2.7.8 and python-3.4.1 and all combinations cause a failure.

I use 'python setup.py install' to install these packages.

GitPython-0.1.7 seems to need ez_setup which in turn fails as it needs setuptools.

GitPython-0.3.2.RC1 seems to need gitdb-0.5.4 which throws up a number of warnings

I understand that python-3.x does not support GitPython, is this still true?

As you can tell by my ramblings, I have am getting a little frustrated and would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Get https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/python/pip-for-windows and point it to your Python34 or Python27 directory. It should set you up with setuptools and easy_install. Good place to start.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/0.3.2.RC1:

> **Installation**
>
> As this version of GitPython depends on *GitDB*, which in turn needs
>   *Async* to work, installation is a bit more complicated if you do a
>   manual installation, instead of using easy_install.